# Adding new column, or accessing a certain column in numpy array

Tags: python

I have a NumPy array, such that

```
results = np.repeat(0.5, 400)
```

If I want to view the column, I can just call `results`. However, I would assume `results[:,0]` should work too, alas it provides the following: IndexError: too many indices for array.

This is an issue as I want to create a new column in the array, however can't do this: `results[:,1] = results[:,0]`.

How do I go about adding a new column to an array?

Answer (score 1):

You're referring to `results` as if it had a single column and 400 rows, however, the array you're creating is a 1D-array and does not have rows and columns as such.

If you want to create a single 2D-array with 1 column and 400 rows containing `0.5`, you can use this:

```
results = np.repeat([[0.5]], 400, axis=0)
```

Then you could add a column with a copy of the first like this:

```
results = np.append(results, results, axis=1)
```

Alternatively, you could do what you did (create a 1D-array) and then just add a dimension to turn it into 2D:

```
results = np.repeat(0.5, 400)
results = np.expand_dims(results, 1)
```

After that, adding a column is the same as before.

Comment: if this is the case, why does results[1:5,] work, indicating row 1 to 5? sorry for the confusion, using Spyder and inspecting the variable makes it seem like a 400x1 array

Comment: `results[1:5,]` gets you the first 5 elements, except for the first one at index 0. It's the same as `results[1:5]` by the way.

Also, my answer was a bit misleading, I now realise. I was only looking at the problem you had, but numpy is supposed to be row-major and that's just a matter of interpreting what's in there. I'm going to update the answer

Comment: So, *why*  `results[1:5,]` works is you are providing a slice to select 4 elements from the first dimension (not 'row' or 'column', just axis 0) and that's what you get.